# Is it possible to limit children to specific components using React with TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Using React with TypeScript, there are several ways to define the type of `children`, like setting it to `JSX.Element` or `React.ReactChild` or extending `PropsWithChildren`. But doing so, is it possible to further limit which particular element that React child can be?

```
function ListItem() {
  return (
    <li>A list item<li>
  );
}

//--------------------

interface ListProps {
  children: React.ReactChild | React.ReactChild[]
}

function List(props: ListProps) {
  return (
    <ul>
      {props.children} // what if I only want to allow elements of type ListItem here?
    </ul>
  );
}
```

Given the above scenario, can `List` be set up in such a way that it only allows children of type `ListItem`? Something akin to the following (invalid) code:

```
interface ListProps {
  children: React.ReactChild<ListItem> | React.ReactChild<ListItem>[]
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't constrain react children like this.

Any react functional component is just a function that has a specific props type and returns `JSX.Element`. This means that if you *render* the component before you pass it a child, then react has no idea what generated that JSX at all, and just passes it along.

And problem is that you render the component with the `<MyComponent>` syntax. So after that point, it's just a generic tree of JSX nodes.

---

This sounds a little like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), however. Typically if you need this, there's a better way to design your api.

Instead, you could make and `items` prop on `List` which takes an array of objects that will get passed as props to `ListItem` inside the `List` component.

For example:

```
function ListItem({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <li>{children}</li>
  );
}

function List(props: { items: string[] }) {
  return (
    <ul>
      {props.items.map((item) => <ListItem>{item}</ListItem> )}
    </ul>
  );
}

const good = <List items={['a', 'b', 'c']} />
```

In this example, you're just typing props, and `List` knows how to generate its own children.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChTMBXAOw2AmrgBlgBnGASRiRAAoBvOGgAWwADYATIowC+ALjiCR4qUmoLk6GADpNGAHIQJSODICUi0nDhEYlKI15XrcADxjgAPn7LJ0ma4A9B6ezmYA3KQy5FS0MPSMLOy8YDhgrAqCwNwgGXDsUMDUAOYA2gC6phb8zrb2js7WrpRioS4u-KkQ6drZPKzaIChgvLx9IBYAvJ5uSZw53uMBgXNcPDNm0e1BLW1wEVHkaAzscMUQRnCTs2zw46yT-KX4KPgANAQARu8EaPjlMjggU8QA)

Answer (score -1):

Here's a barebones example that I am using for a "wizard" with multiple steps.  It uses a primary component WizardSteps (plural) and a sub-component WizardStep (singular), which has a "label" property that is rendered in the main WizardSteps component.  The key in making this work correctly is the Children.map(...) call, which ensures that React treats "children" as an array, and also allows Typescript and your IDE to work correctly.

```
const WizardSteps: FunctionComponent<WizardStepsProps> & WizardSubComponents = ({children}) => {
    const steps = Children.map(children, child => child); /* Treat as array with requisite type */

    return (
        <div className="WizardSteps">
            <header>
                <!-- Note the use of step.props.label, which is properly typecast -->
                {steps.map(step => <div className="WizardSteps__step">{step.props.label}</div>)}
            </header>
            <main>
                <!-- Here you can render the body of each WizardStep child component -->
                {steps.map(step => <div className="WizardSteps__body">{step}</div>)}
            </main>
        </div>
    );
}

const Step: FunctionComponent<WizardStepProp> = ({label, onClick}) => {
    return <span className="WizardSteps__label">
        {label}
    </span>
}

WizardSteps.Step = Step;

type WizardSubComponents = {
    Step: FunctionComponent<WizardStepProp>
}

type WizardStepsProps = {
    children: ReactElement<WizardStepProp> | Array<ReactElement<WizardStepProp>>
};

type WizardStepProp = {
    label: string
    onClick?: string
    children?: ReactNode
}
```

Comment: This seems dangerous because while it does apply the type to the children inside WizardSteps, it doesn't seem to prevent me from providing children of other types, so it makes TypeScript potentially claim wrong types. For this to be safe, the code `<WizardSteps><div /></WizardSteps />` should not compile.

Answer (score -3):

Absolutely. You just need to use `React.ReactElement` for the proper generics.

```js
interface ListItemProps {
   text: string
}

interface ListProps {
   children: React.ReactElement<ListItemProps> | React.ReactElement<ListItemProps>[];
}
```

Edit - I've created an example CodeSandbox for you:

https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-cannon-16kjo?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Can you provide proof of usage, because I'm fairly sure this doesn't work as you expect https://tsplay.dev/ND574m

Comment: I get a red line claiming `ListItem` refers to a value instead of a type, asking if I meant `typeof ListItem`. Using that allows me to continue, however it doesn't appear to restrict the children given to `List`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @MagnusBull - Sorry, I just caught that `ListItem` is a function, rather than a type. You will need to make a type for the ListItem's Properties (`ListItemProps`) and refer to that as the generic.

Comment: @MagnusBull - I've updated the original answer to include a link to a quick Typescript / React CodeSandbox for you to check out in order to tackle this. I've done this many times for things like <Tabs><Tab /><Tab /></Tabs>

Comment: As @AlexWayne said, the `React.ReactElement` type doesn't work like you'd expect.  Yes it takes generics but they are really misleading because basically all JSX is the same no matter how it was generated.

Comment: But if I add `<div>test</div>` to your example as a child of `List`, I get no type errors.

Comment: @AlexWayne - Thanks for pointing that out. Now I'm questioning everything I thought I knew about Typescript and React. :) Or, just another Wednesday :)