# array of html elements or strings typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Put simply I would like to have either `stings` or `HTMLInputElements` as my type.

```
  const tableHeaders = [
    <input type="checkbox" />,
    "Some String",
    "Another Some String",
  ];
```

### Component

```
import React, { ReactChildren } from 'react';

interface TableProps {
  headers: (string | HTMLInputElement)[];
}

export const Table = ({ headers }: TableProps) => (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          {headers.map((name: string) => (
            <th key={name}>{name}</th>
          ))}
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
);
```

### Error

```
Type '(string | Element)[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
  Type 'string | Element' is not assignable to type 'string'.
    Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'string'.  TS2322

    160 |       {!noResults && (
    161 |         <TableShell data-id="TableShell">
  > 162 |           <Table headers={tableHeaders}>
        |                  ^
    163 |             {state.map(
    164 |               ({
    165 |                 id,
```

### Desired outcome:

To have arbitrary headers to be any html input and or a string.

[image]

### A possible solution?

```
import React, { ReactChildren } from 'react';

type headerType = ReactChildren | React.ReactNode | string;

interface TableProps {
  headers: headerType[];
}

export const Table = ({ headers }: TableProps) => (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          {headers.map(
            (name: headerType, index) => (
              <th key={`${index}_tableHeader`}>{name}</th>
            )
          )}
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
);
```

Comment: What the question?

Comment: How can I avoid the errors I guess lol

Comment: I know what the *problem* is, but not how to solve it. The problem is that your `tableHeaders` array contains `string | JSX.Element`, not `string | HTMLInputElement`. `HTMLInputElement` is an actual DOM `input` element, but the JSX `<input ... />` doesn't create an `HTMLInputElement`, it creates a `JSX.Element` that tells React to create an `input` element when it's used, which is a different thing. I don't know how to say "Only a specific kind of JSX element is allowed here" or even if you can (`JSX.Element` has no generic type parameters).

Comment: The irritating thing is, I could swear I've had, and solved, this problem in the past. :-|

Comment: I think this answers it (you won't like the answer :-) ): [*Is it possible to limit children to specific components using React with TypeScript?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66465192/is-it-possible-to-limit-children-to-specific-components-using-react-with-typescr)

Comment: I think the answer there means that you'd make your props interface like this: `interface TableProps { headers: (string | InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>)[]; }` and then declare `tableHeaders` as `(string | InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>)[]` and instead of `<input type="checkbox" />` that entry would be `{type: "checkbox"}`. Then `Table` would have to map `headers` when outputting: `{headers.map(header => typeof header === "string" ? header : <input {...header} />)}`.

Comment: Ye, very very interesting :D I came up with a "solution" however reading the article posted maybe its a bad idea. However your comment gave me the realization that it auto resolves to a JSX object rather than the HTML element.

Comment: Amusingly, I think the way I solved it before was exactly the kind of end-run described in that answer: Accepting the information to create the element, rather than the element itself. I don't feel like I've seen that specific answer before, but maybe I've seen a different version of it. Anyway, I think this does qualify for marking as a duplicate so I'll do that if you agree. Either way, good luck with it!

Comment: I think I'm on the fence if its a duplicate. As, mostly, reading the question linked. it is telling me that my solution is a bad pattern I believe? If you agree it is, then I would say, yep, lets mark it as a duplicate. But interested in hearing your thoughts on the solution I posted in the question :)

Comment: Seems fine to me. It's more open than the original limit, which specifically required `input` elements, but if you're happy with more open, that's cool. Beware that using the `index` as the `key` won't work if the headers array ever changes while the component is mounted. (There's also no need to add a suffix to the key, there's nothing else in the array to differentiate it from and keys aren't rendered.)

Comment: In my head, if I used `index` anywhere else... this would cause a clash in the indexes? Unless they scoped? :)