# Only allow a specific element as a prop checked by Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How to define that only a specific element type is allowed to be passed as a prop to a component?

Let's say I have a component which has a prop `divider` and it should be typed in a way so that only `<svg>` elements can be passed to this prop.

```
import { ElementType, ReactElement } from 'react';

type Props = {
  divider: ReactElement<'svg'>;
};

export function SVGClipPathSection({ divider: Divider }: Props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Divider />
      Blub
    </div>
  );
}
```

This leads to

> JSX element type 'Divider' does not have any construct or call signatures.ts(2604)

What would be the appropriate type?

### Update #1

```
type Props = {
  divider: SVGElement;
};

export function SVGClipPathSection({ divider }: Props) {
  return <div>{divider}</div>;
}
```

This leads to:

```
error TS2322: Type 'SVGElement' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
  Type 'SVGElement' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactPortal': key, type, props

6   return <div>{divider}</div>;
                ~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:1375:9
    1375         children?: ReactNode | undefined;
                 ~~~~~~~~
    The expected type comes from property 'children' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>'
```

Comment: Are you missing a `{` in your example? The `type Props` declaration looks rather odd.

Comment: There was a previous question about this a few weeks back that I can't find now, but the answer was: No, you can't do that (at a type level).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think what you want to do is possible.

You can, however, traverse your component array and filter those of the type you want, possibly raising a warning if there are children of unwanted type.

```
const filtered = divider.filter(e => React.isValidElement(e) && e.type === 'svg');

if (filtered.length !== divider.length) {
  console.warn('divider elements must be of type <svg/>');
}

const typed = filtered as ReactElement<React.ComponentProps<'svg'>>[];
```

**Edit:** You have a good explanation of why what you want might not be possible in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66465461/1077412):

> Any react functional component is just a function that has a specific
> props type and returns `JSX.Element`. This means that if you render the
> component before you pass it a child, then react has no idea what
> generated that JSX at all, and just passes it along.
>
> And problem is that you render the component with the `<MyComponent>`
> syntax. So after that point, it's just a generic tree of JSX nodes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't want to type check the children, but one of the props.

Comment: Sorry, @Robin, I have updated my answer to apply to a regular property

Comment: Thank you. I leave the question open, because I hope to find a solution with type checking, but I appreciate your idea of a warning!

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML Element interfaces to define element type.
So for your example, you can define the divider type as `SVGElement`.
Please refer this, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API#interfaces

```js
type Props = {
  divider: SVGElement;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. TS throws: `TS2604: JSX element type 'Divider' does not have any construct or call signatures`

Comment: Then you are using it in the dom element without initiating it. Would you please share it how you are using it? 
Are you using directly in the JSX `{divider}` ?

Comment: This leads to: `TS2746: This JSX tag's 'children' prop expects a single child of type 'ReactNode', but multiple children were provided.`

Comment: Or if it's a single child: `TS2322: Type 'SVGElement' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
  Type 'SVGElement' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactPortal': key, type, props`

Comment: Excuse me but would you please share your code part with it?